# Method calling itself not executing fully

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, console, stdin

Here's a simple example to illustrate the problem:

```
class Test
{
    static void PrintName()
    {
        Console.Out.Write("Enter your name: "); 
        string name = Console.In.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(name);

        Console.Out.Write("\nEnter R to restart: ");
        char r = Convert.ToChar(Console.In.Read());

        if (r.ToString().Equals("r", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            PrintName();
        else
            Environment.Exit(0);

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintName();
    }
}
```

Basically, PrintName asks to restart itself. On the first run it accepts the user input and displays the name fine. When asked to repeat the procedure, it just displays the prompt and asks if you want to restart. It skips past waiting for input or displaying output.

UPDATE: Output is:

```
Enter your name: Naven
Naven

Enter R to restart: r
Enter your name:

Enter R to restart: r
Enter your name:

Enter R to restart:
```

Comment: The problem is the Console.Read() function.  See [this related question][1] for a solution.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048467/why-is-console-readline-not-executing-as-expected

Comment: @Crono See update for what happens when I run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an expected behavior. 
`ReadLine` will read characters until it finds `'\n'`
in the other hand `Read` will not read `'\n'` so when you read the command **r** you will have a `'\n'` in your buffer and so you arrive in `ReadLine` and pass directly.

so you have to clean the buffer a simple `ReadLine` will do just that.

```
class Test
{
    static void PrintName()
    {
        Console.Out.Write("Enter your name: ");
        string name = Console.In.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(name);

        Console.Out.Write("\nEnter R to restart: ");
        char r = Convert.ToChar(Console.In.Read());

        if (r.ToString().Equals("r", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            Console.In.ReadLine();
            PrintName();
        }
        else
            Environment.Exit(0);

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just used `Console.ReadLine()`. Is it better to use `Console.In.ReadLine()` ?

Comment: The problem with the Read function is that when it finish it might leave the buffer with some chars that might affect what you do later. so if you use it you have to be aware of that, in other hand the use of ReadLine is more clean. and besides ReadLine use Read and makes sure to remove '\n'